# R - Shiny - customize headerPanel with HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I do not know CSS/HTML well. I am trying to modify the headerPanel so that the logo aligns to very left of the page, next the title and the processing gif is aligned to very right of the headerPanel, all in a line. Any help is appreciated

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",

                  tags$head(
                         tags$style(HTML('
      .shiny-output-error-validation { font-family:courier; color:#B54B4B;

                                     }
    '))
    ),

    tags$head(tags$style(type ="text/css", "a{color:#4d3a7d;}","body {background-color: #fff; }")),

    headerPanel(
      list( tags$div( style = "font-family: 'Lobster', cursive; font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.1; color: #4d3a7d", tags$h1( 'MyAPP.Title')),

           tags$div(style="float:left", tags$img(src="Logo.png", height=75)),

           conditionalPanel(condition=" $('html').hasClass('shiny-busy')",

                            tags$div ( style="float:right; padding-right:30px; padding-top:10px;",
                                     tags$img(src="loading-gif-animation.gif",height=50,width=50)),
                            tags$div ( style="float:right; padding-right:30px; padding-top:10px; color:blue;
                                          background-color:white; font-family:arial; font-size:18 px",
                                     "Processing... Please wait...")
                            )
           )),

    sidebarPanel(
```

Comment: Can you comment on what's wrong with the question? Downvoting without comment doesn't help me learn how to ask better questions.

Comment: Try float: left

Comment: Thanks for comment! I have actually. Header panel has float:left in the tags$div for the image

Comment: Maybe try "position: absolute" "top: 0" and "left: 0" (all combined)